# How can I replace %2C with a <comma> in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
 #&q=car&category=Car%20Audio%2CAccessories&brand=
```

I borrowed a this function from a previous question asked on SO:

```
function insertParam(key, value)
{
key = escape(key); value = escape(value);

var kvp = document.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');

var i=kvp.length; var x; while(i--) 
{
    x = kvp[i].split('=');

    if (x[0]==key)
    {
            x[1] = value;
            kvp[i] = x.join('=');
            break;
    }
}

if(i<0) {kvp[kvp.length] = [key,value].join('=');}

//this will reload the page, it's likely better to store this until finished

document.location.hash = kvp.join('&'); 
}
```

I use it like this:

```
    insertParam("category",xy);
    insertParam("brand",zy);
```

My problem is it is decoding comma's to %2C. I know I can handle the characters on the server side, but how can I make it look pretty with javascript? By pretty I mean replace %2c with a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>`decodeURIComponent(foo)` is the thing you are looking for.</s>

**Edit**: Misread your question.

Use `replace(/&/g, "%26").replace(/=/g, "%3D")` instead of `escape` on key and value to do this.

None of the 3 functions `encodeURI`, `encodeURIComponent` or `encode` work for this task, because they either encode commas or don't encode `&=`.

Answer (score 17):

I do not know why in the previous answer that was striked out, but the answer was correct.

```
alert(decodeURIComponent('%2C'));
```

So, you break your query strings into elements, splitting by & symbol. Than you split the results by = symbol and apply  decodeURIComponent on both name and the value.

ps: `key = escape(key); value = escape(value);` you should not use escape here (it is different for different browsers. and by 'different' I meant IE). Use encodeURIComponent.

pps: `because they either encode commas or don't encode &=`???

```
alert(encodeURIComponent('&=,'));
```

outputs `%26%3D%2C`

Comment: RPM wants to store key-value pairs in the hash, seperated by `=` and `&` (like GET-parameters). In order to do so properly, `=` and `&` have to be encoded, which can be done using `decodeURIComponent` or `escape`. Both of these functions, however, also encode `,` which is not wanted. `decodeURI` does not encode `=` or `&` so it's not suitable either.

Comment: It "does not look pretty" (not my personal opinion). Also it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me for undoing `encodeURIComponent()` on URIs that contain commas:

```
.replace(/%2C/g,",")
```